# Javascript object literal notation executing all values

Tags: javascript, object, literals

I want based on the case execute a function, out of a choice of 5 functions. and then take the return value of that function, use that to execute one extra function ( same for each case )

All my functions are synchronous I believe.

```
var x = require('./file2.js')

export default (metadata) => {
    return (req, next) => {
      var fn = new x (req, next, metadata)
      var metric = (req.body.metric)
      var choices = {
                "1": fn.one(),
                "2": fn.one(),
                "3": fn.one(),
                "4": fn.one(),
                "5": fn.two(),
                "6": fn.three(),
                "7": fn.four(),
                "8": fn.five()
      };
var jql = choices[metric]// When I put console.log's in all the function (one through five) they all print out.
```

file2.js:

```
var x = function (req, next, metadata) {
this.req = req;
this.next = next;
this.start = metadata.body.start;
}

x.prototype.one = function (){
   var jql = ['test',
    'AND ' + this.start].join("\n")
   return jql
}
module.exports = x;
```

Comment: are you sure x is defined? ie. did you require the correct file? try doing console.log(x) and see what happens

Comment: `fn.1` isn't valid syntax. Property identifier syntax may not start with a number.

Comment: I messed up by trying to simplify the functions. 
fn.1() is actually jiraCall.getLeakage()

Comment: Do you have a different variable named choices defined anywhere?/could you show the rest of the first file? This is confusing because your code looks fine

Comment: Thanks, the code ended up being fine. I was just low in confidence I suppose.
the problem ended up being in "2", as I was passing a stringified variable coming from the request that seemed right because it evaluated to "2". but when I tried  it unstringified it then evaluated properly.

Comment: ahh i thought it might have something to do with that. Cool, glad you figured it out :)

Comment: would you happend to know why all the cases are executing?

Comment: If you solved this, you might want to just delete your question.

Comment: `let o = {foo: bar.baz()};` invokes `bar.baz` to create _foo_ on `o`. `let o = {foo: () => bar.baz()};` creates a function for _foo_ which will invoke `bar.baz` when `o.foo` is invoked

Comment: Paul that was incredibly helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to do what I think you trying to do then you need something like this:

```
/*
 Since you want to call a method on an instance of a class, first bind them to 
 the proper scope (might want to rethink the name fn). 
 Function#bind creates a new function that executes with the proper scope
*/
const one = fn.one.bind(fn)
const two = fn.two.bind(fn)
const three = fn.three.bind(fn)
const four = fn.four.bind(fn)
const five = fn.five.bind(fn)

// Create your object of choices with these functions
const choices = {
  "1": one,
  "2": one,
  "3": one,
  "4": one,
  "5": two,
  "6": three,
  "7": four,
  "8": five
}

// Then you can use it like this:
choices['1'](/* whatever arguments it needs */)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your answer is right on the money.

since in ES6 let binds the scope,

would you recommend

let choices = {
"1": () => fn.one()
};

And then calling
choices["1"]();

Comment: It doesn't really matter `"1": () => fn.one()` is fine as well